# Setting a value in java classes. Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a java card game but am having trouble setting the card. I am taking in values such as `2H 3D 4S 5C 6H` in the main function. I am trying to put these values into my Card class but when I try to set my rank I get a nullpointerexception error.

I am new to java programing and can not figure out why this is happening. Any suggestions? Am I not allowed to make an array of Cards?

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();

    String[] player1arr = new String[5];
    String[] player2arr = new String[5];

    Card[] player1 = new Card[5];
    Card[] player2 = new Card[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        player1arr[i] = sc.next();
        char first = player1arr[i].charAt(0);
        int rank = Character.getNumericValue(first); //error
        player1[i].setRank(rank); 


    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        player2arr[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println(player2arr[i]);
    }  
  }
}

class Card{
    private int rank;
    private char suit;

    public int getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int r){
        rank = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post the error trace.
Additionally, you are not creating Card instances in your array. You are just allocating memory for the array itself, but, with null Card objects in it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array of objects, the array is initially filled with the default value of null.
Call

```
cards[i] = new Card();
```

to initialize all the objects within the array :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate Cards in your main method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    player1arr[i] = sc.next();
    char first = player1arr[i].charAt(0);
    int rank = Character.getNumericValue(first); //error
    player1[i] = new Card();
    player1[i].setRank(rank); 


}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Much thanks